# When were modern mats introduced into Judo, and did it change the way the art could be taught?

Tags: judo, equipment, safety, protective-equipment

I've read that the original mats were tatami on hard floor, and I have to wonder if people also trained outdoors on dirt.  There's obviously a greater chance of injury, compared to modern mats.  Do modern mats facilitate the teaching, and, if so, why?

Comment: Ranting comment: People don't learn to fall and roll properly ;)

Comment: As a complete outsider, I see a few factors, but none has to do with *teaching*. The obvious 1): you need some sort of padding for training because a hard fall can really injure or kill. 2) Maybe it's because of gymnastics, but modern mats are far easier to get. 3) Modern mats are made of water-resistant plastic and rubber, and that's a big plus when you have sweaty people rolling around on it. Woven materials like tatami absorb water, and that's a big mold problem you can't really fix.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking I unfortunately know a several years of experience aikidoka who can't fall on grass (without a loud thud! ohhhh I can't get up now)

Comment: @Vorac That's why I do some falls and rolls on plain wooden floor from time to time. There is a group in the Kodokan which praises itself to train without mats on the wood iirc :)

Comment: What is a "modern" mat?

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Appreciate the comment/insight.  In my Chinese tradition, people train on hard floors, and I'm lucky to be able to on flagstones with irregularities like in the old days.  The softest surface I've free sparred on is grass or carpet.  (For pakua you can't use mats b/c you can't spin without wrenching the knee or ankle, and even grass ain't great.  Note that spins take place body to body, such that it's "not turning your back" on an opponent.)   But I also think safety is important, especially for kids!

Comment: @Mattm softer mats that protect the skull, made of modern materials.  (Don't use mats so not an expert on the subject.)  But I do think about safety, especially in teaching kids or adults without a high degree of physical training.  I've been thrown on tile, dirt and grass, but the level of physical training always kept me from getting hurt, in some cases even landing on my feet.

Comment: @Mattm I was kind of famous for getting thrown on tile by one of my older brothers who was the best grappler when I stepped out of life.  It scandalized the other students that he would do it, but I appreciated it, and never got hurt b/c of the ability to use my waist to adjust in the air.  (It was important that he made me aware of my openings and vulnerabilities, and kept my ego in check;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judo has always used mats. In *Judo Memoirs of Jigoro Kano*, Kano (the founder of judo), measured practice spaces by the number of tatami mats.

> The warehouse afforded a practice area of only ten tamami mats, and there were square pillars here and there.

The primary protection against injuries is technique and cooperation, not mats. The beginning lessons of judo focus on the practice of falling (*ukemi*) and throwing for safety. Falling training aims to either roll out of falls or spread impact over a large area (arms, legs, back/side) and to protect the head, spine, and other joints. Throw training aims to put the partner onto their back, but not the head or the spine. There are no points for throwing someone on their head, and trying to land on your head to avoid giving up a score will disqualify you. In training two partners each try to throw the other, but not in injurious ways. Although mats provide some protection against head and other injuries, if you land on your head with any regularity, you will get badly injured.

Competition judo mats are not plush. There are "crash pads", which are significantly thicker (~15cm) and softer mats that inhibit movement because they are so soft. You can't really have matches on top of them because you sink into them too much while trying to move. Some practictioners like to use crash pads for heavy throwing practice, but crash pads are not necessary and not all facilities have them.

So in my opinion, modern mats have not greatly affected the practice of judo. Judo has always used mats to improve safety, but the primary safety features of judo are inherent in its design and not in mats.

Answer (score -3):

> public gymnasiums started to appear in the US in the early 1800’s,Inspired by early health/vitality philosophies of various cultural movements. Eventually, gyms made their way into schools and universities, and even became large independent organizations, like the YMCA and such. Gym mats evolved in the late 1800's;the desire to have surfaces you could fall or land on, and soon wood floors; were replaced by soft surfaces like cotton stuffed pads and mattresses.

[Source](https://rubberflooringexperts.com/gym-buyers-guide/flooring-mat-history/)

Comment: How does this answer the question how mats changed the way Judo was trained after it **evidently not had been trained on mats for some time**?

Comment: Hi @LazyReader, please read [this help section article](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). When using other's work as a reference it is important to attribute it in your answer.